# What does "convolve k filters" mean in the AlphaGo paper?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, convolution, alphago, filters, convolutional-layers

On page 27 of the [DeepMind AlphaGo paper](http://airesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/deepmind-mastering-go.pdf) appears the following sentence:

> The first hidden layer zero pads the input into a $23 \times 23$ image, then convolves $k$ filters of kernel size $5 \times 5$ with stride $1$ with the input image and applies a rectifier nonlinearity.

What does "convolves $k$ filters" mean here?

Does it mean the following:

> The first hidden layer is a convolutional layer with $k$ groups of $(19 \times 19)$ neurons, where there is a kernel of $(5 \times 5 \times numChannels + 1)$ parameters (input weights plus a bias term) used by all the neurons of each group. $numChannels$ is 48 (the number of feature planes in the input image stack).
>
> All $(19 \times 19 \times k)$ neurons' outputs are available to the second hidden layer (which happens to be another convolutional layer, but could in principle be fully connected).

?

Comment: I believe it means they perform convolution with $k$ filters in the given layer (this is if I'm not getting my terminology confused)

Comment: Regarding your first question, I agree with @DavidIreland. I am pretty sure that they convolve $k$ different filters with the same $23 \times 23$ image, where each of the filters has the same depth as the input images, provided you're performing a 2D convolution. The $k$ is a hyper-parameter there. I am not so sure about the second paragraph. I would need to think about it a little more.